# Check if two strings share the same pattern of repeated characters

Tags: c#, regex

Is there an efficient Regex to assert that two string share the same pattern of repeated characters.

```
("tree", "loaa") => true
("matter", "essare") => false
("paper", "mime") => false
("acquaintance", "mlswmodqmdlp") => true
("tree", "aoaa") => false
```

Event if it's not through Regex, I'm looking for the most efficient way to perform the task

Comment: this is a valid pattern  : ("tree", "aoaa")  => true ?

Comment: Not sure if regex is the right tool for this kind of pattern matching. Why not translate each encountered letter to another, known one - and then do the same with the second string, and then compare the two. So, the first character found is always a, the second is always b, etc. Not... efficient. But.

Comment: By "same pattern", you don't mean "same repeating characters", but rather the strings contain the same character position/entropy? So, 'abc' = 'def', 'aab' = 'ccd', 'fggh' != 'abcd'?

Comment: think (different) characters needs to be repeated at the same place/position in both strings? 1233 = 5677 or 7857 = 9519

Comment: @Istern: No, that would be an invalid pattern

Comment: How do you define "patter of repeated characters"?

Comment: @MarcoToniut is your third example actually correct? because the first `c` is mapped to `l` and the last `c` is mapped to `v`.

Comment: @m.buettner: You are right! fixed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to walk through both strings manually at the same time and build up a dictionary (that matces corresponding characters) while you are doing it:

```
if(input1.Length != input2.Length)
    return false;
var characterMap = new Dictionary<char, char>();
for(int i = 0; i < input1.Length; i++)
{
    char char1 = input1[i];
    char char2 = input2[i];
    if(!characterMap.ContainsKey(char1))
    {
        if (characterMap.ContainsValue(char2))
            return false;
        characterMap[char1] = char2;
    }
    else
    {
        if(char2 != characterMap[char1])
            return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

In the same manner you could construct a regex. This is certainly not more efficient for a single comparison, but it might be useful if you want to check one repetition pattern against multiple strings in the future. This time we associate characters with their back-references.

```
var characterMap = new Dictionary<char, int>();
string regex = "^";
int nextBackreference = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    char character = input[i];
    if(!characterMap.ContainsKey(character))
    {
        regex += "(.)";
        characterMap[character] = nextBackreference;
        nextBackreference++;
    }
    else
    {
        regex += (@"\" + characterMap[character]);
    }
}
regex += "$";
```

For `matter` it will generate this regex: `^(.)(.)(.)\3(.)(.)$`. For `acquaintance` this one: `^(.)(.)(.)(.)\1(.)(.)(.)\1\6\2(.)$`. If could of course optimize this regular expression a bit afterwards (e.g. for the second one `^(.)(.)..\1.(.).\1\3\2$`), but in any case, this would give you a reusable regex that checks against this one specific repetition pattern.

**EDIT:** Note that the given regex solution has a caveat. It allows mapping of multiple characters in the input string onto a single character in the test strings (which would contradict your last example). To get a correct regex solution, you would have to go a step further to disallow characters already matched. So `acquaintance` would have to generate this awful regular expression:

```
^(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1|\2)(.)(?!\1|\2|\3)(.)\1(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)(.)(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5)(.)(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)(.)\1\6\2(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6|\7)(.)$
```

And I cannot think of an easier way, since you cannot use backreferences in (negated) character classes. So maybe, if you **do** want to assert this as well, regular expressions are not the best option in the end.

Disclaimer: I am not really a .NET guru, so this might not be the best practice in walking through arrays in building up a dictionary or string. But I hope you can use it as a starting point.

Comment: I was writing the exact same answer.

Comment: @lstern Likewise, but I couldn't get the code out fast enough and lumped for a descriptive, if somewhat less explanative, version.

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it using a regex, but in code I would run through both strings one character at a time, comparing as I go and building a comparison list:

```
t = l
r = o
e = a
etc.
```

Prior to adding each comparison, I'd check to see if a character from the first string already existed in the list. If the corresponding character from the second string does not match the comparison list then the string patterns don't match.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Accepted code is now correct. This one will linger here as an alternative (which is less good in almost any sense).

```
    private static List<int> FindIndices(string str, char c, int ind)
    {
        var retval = new List<int>();
        int last = ind, temp;
        while (0 < (temp = str.IndexOf(c, last)))
        {
            retval.Add(temp);
            last = temp + 1;
        }           
        return retval;
    }

    public static int[] CanonicalForm(string s)
    {
        string table = String.Empty;
        var res = new int[s.Length];
        int marker = 0;
        int lastInd;

        for(int i=0; i < s.Length-1; ++i)
        {
            if (table.Contains(s[i]))
                continue;

            table += s[i];              
            lastInd = i+1;

            if (s.IndexOf(s[i], lastInd) > 0)
                res[i] = ++marker;
            else
                continue;

            foreach (var v in FindIndices(s, s[i], lastInd))
                res[v] = marker;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

And the comparison:

```
    public static bool ComparePatterns(string s1, string s2)
    {
        return ( (s1.Length == s2.Length) && CanonicalForm(s1).SequenceEqual(CanonicalForm(s2)) );
    }
```

So the point is to build a canonical form which can be later compared. This is not especially smart but does give correct results.

Comment: Fixed that one typo and I added another check to disallow mapping of multiple characters onto one (which I suppose is what you meant by "isn't correct") for the first implementation (and pointed out why it would be not reasonable to try to do the same thing with regexes).

Answer (score 1):

Only because I love LINQ: :)

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Map("tree") == Map("loaa"));
    Console.WriteLine(Map("matter") == Map("essare"));
    Console.WriteLine(Map("paper") == Map("mime"));
    Console.WriteLine(Map("acquaintance") == Map("mlswmodqmdlp"));
    Console.WriteLine(Map("tree") == Map("aoaa"));  
}

public string Map(string input)
{
    var seen = new Dictionary<char,int>();
    var index = 0;
    return string.Join(
      string.Empty, 
      input.Select(c =>seen.ContainsKey(c) ? seen[c] : seen[c] = index++));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just came across this same problem. and i wrote a piece of python code for it. it's rather straightforward, no extra modules to import. the basic idea is to translate the two given strings to a new pattern string, respectively, using the relationship between ascii characters and their corresponding numerical values. finally compare the two pattern strings.

```
def SamePattern(s1, s2):
  i = j = 97
  p1 = p2 = ""

  for index1, l1 in enumerate(s1):
    if l1 not in s1[0:index1]:
      p1 += chr(i)
      i += 1
    else:
      p1 += chr(97 + s1.index(l1))

  for index2, l2 in enumerate(s2): 
    if l2 not in s2[0:index2]:
      p2 += chr(j)
      j += 1
    else:
      p2 += chr(97 + s2.index(l2))
      
  if p1 == p2:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```